# Creating a Time Series from an Existing Data Set

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I want to convert the following data into a time series - so I can use `autoplot()`.

How do I do this so that the "Year" column is what would be on the x-axis? (I know the format for date has to be 01-01-2006, I'm ok with that):

```
Team  PTS    W   GF   GA     S    SA   Year
NSH    88   38  214  233  2382  2365   2014
NSH   104   47  226  202  2614  2304   2015
NSH    96   41  224  213  2507  2231   2016
NSH    94   41  238  220  2557  2458   2017
NSH   117   53  261  204  2641  2650   2018
```

Using `as.ts()` yields the Year column in some very large & unusable numbers. Thanks! I want to use the new time series frame for forecasting: ARIMA, VARs, etc.

Comment: `autoplot` probably doesn't do what you want https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/autoplot . Why not plot with `plot()` or `ggplot()`?

Comment: True, but it would streamline my process if I could just throw it in `autoplot()`. I did it easily with `ggplot(NSH_stats, aes(Year, PTS)) +
  geom_line()`

Comment: so you can make a function `plot_ts <- function(df){ggplot(df, aes(Year, PTS)) + geom_line())}` then anywhere you can easily: `plot_ts(NSH_stats)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you want:

```
df_ts <- ts(df[ , setdiff(names(df), c("Team", "Year"))],
            start = 2014,
            end = 2018,
            frequency = 1)
class(df_ts)
#[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

I excluded the columns `Team` and `Year` from the coercion because the `Year` seems uneeded and `Team` is of type character. From `?ts`

> Time series must have at least one observation, and although they need not be numeric there is very limited support for non-numeric series.

Use `ggfortify::autoplot.ts` for plotting

```
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(df_ts)
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Team = c("NSH", "NSH", "NSH", "NSH", "NSH"), PTS = c(88L, 
104L, 96L, 94L, 117L), W = c(38L, 47L, 41L, 41L, 53L), GF = c(214L, 
226L, 224L, 238L, 261L), GA = c(233L, 202L, 213L, 220L, 204L), 
    S = c(2382L, 2614L, 2507L, 2557L, 2641L), SA = c(2365L, 2304L, 
    2231L, 2458L, 2650L), Year = 2014:2018), .Names = c("Team", 
"PTS", "W", "GF", "GA", "S", "SA", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

---

**edit**

One way to show missing observation in your plot would be to turn implicit missing observations into explicit missing observations. I will use `tidyr`'s `complete()`

```
library(tidyr)
df_complete <- complete(df_incomplete, Year = min(Year):max(Year))
df_complete_ts <- ts(df_complete[ , setdiff(names(df_complete), c("Team", "Year"))],
                     start = 2011,
                     frequency = 1)
autoplot(df_complete_ts)
```

[image]

**data2**

```
df_incomplete <- structure(list(Team = c("NSH", "NSH", "NSH", "NSH", "NSH", "NSH", 
"NSH"), PTS = c(88L, 88L, 88L, 104L, 96L, 94L, 117L), W = c(38L, 
38L, 38L, 47L, 41L, 41L, 53L), GF = c(214L, 214L, 214L, 226L, 
224L, 238L, 261L), GA = c(233L, 233L, 233L, 202L, 213L, 220L, 
204L), S = c(2382L, 2382L, 2382L, 2614L, 2507L, 2557L, 2641L), 
    SA = c(2365L, 2365L, 2365L, 2304L, 2231L, 2458L, 2650L), 
    Year = c(2011L, 2012L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L)), .Names = c("Team", 
"PTS", "W", "GF", "GA", "S", "SA", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Works. My full data set starts at 2006, but I have a missing year (2013), is there a way to start/stop the plot in the middle, or would I have to create a fake row for that year?

Comment: @papelr Updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome thank you - 2013 was an NHL lockout year, is why

Answer (score 2):

I have had success using ts() function in R. The code would look something like this for yearly data.

```
df <- ts(data, frequency = 1, start = 2014)
autoplot(df)
```

This should give you the results you want.